# Display the corresponding horizontal and vertical histograms in java

Tags: java, arrays

I just found a good question about arrays in java and I'd like to solve it

This is the question and expected output Example:
[image]

I've already written a correct way to print horizontally.
My approach to write vertically is:

```
public static void verticalHistogram(int[] array, int maximum) {
    int one=0, two=0 , three=0, four=0, five=0;

    for (int i=0; i< array.length; i++) {
        if(array[i] < 20) {
            one +=1;
        }
        else if (array[i] >= 20 && array[i] <= 39 ) {
            two +=1;
        }
        else if (array[i] >= 40 && array[i] <= 59 ) {
            three +=1;
        }
        else if (array[i] >= 60 && array[i] <= 79 ) {
            four +=1;
        }
        else {
            five +=1;
        }
    }
    int arr[] = {one,two,three,four,five};

    for (int i = 0; i < maximum; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            if (arr[j] > i) {
                System.out.print("*      ");
            } else {
                System.out.print("       ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println("00-19  20-39  40-59  60-79  80-100 \n");
}
```

Comment: What is your approach to print vertically? Where did you stuck?

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < maximum; i++) {
     for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
         if (arr[j] > i) {
             System.out.print("*      ");
         } else {
             System.out.print("       ");
         }
     }
     System.out.println();
 }
 System.out.println("00-19  20-39  40-59  60-79  80-100 \n");`

This is my code for vertical histogram it's printing the * top to bottom  i need  to print from bottom to top!

Comment: @Benjamin Hi, I've edited my post and add the code that i wrote for vertical printing !! Please Check and suggest me!! Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Overally your approach is correct:

1. First you create a histogram array from the input array. (this is what you already have)
2. You get the `maximum` value of the histogram array to know how many rows to print (you need to write it)
3. For each row starting from the `maximum` row and for each element in histogram, print the `*` if the histogram of the adequate cell should be visible, e.g.

```
for (int row = maximum; row > 0; --row) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        // if value of hist[j] >= row then print a star else dont print it
    }
}
```